# A thread private list but shared with methods

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, thread-local-storage

I need to launch multiple threads, but each thread would have its own list. This means, the lists are not to be shared, but they will be accessed by different methods.

```
class foo()
{
    //put the list definition here as a property?

    public main()
    {
        launchthread(threadMethod1)
    }

    public void threadMethod1()
    {
        // create a list instance here?
        // do something about the list, modify data in it
        threadMethod2();
    }

    public void threadMethod2()
    {
        // do something about list, modify data in it
    }
}
```

How should I properly define the list, where to put the definition? and is it has anything to do with thread-safe if I only want to have a thread private list?
I am looking for options other than passing the list as parameter for `threadmethod2`.

Assuming that I don't need to use `ConcurrentBag/SynchronizedCollection` or worry about the lock stuff?

Comment: Create it in `threadMethod1`, pass it as a parameter to `threadMethod2`?

Comment: Or create a class that contains the list and the methods, and use a different instance in each thread?

Comment: Are you hinting at thread local storage?   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I right that you are goind to start your threads something like this:

```
class Foo<T>()
{
    List<T> TLS;

    public main()
    {
        launchThread(threadMethod1)
    }

    public void threadMethod1()
    {
        TLS = new List<T>()
        // TLS.Add(); HERE
        threadMethod2();
    }

    public void threadMethod2()
    {
        // TLS.Add(); HERE
    }
}
```

If so, then it completely thread-safe for you, and you no need in `ConcurrentCollection`-class in your `foo` definition, as there is only one thread which will access this variable. You don't need to add the list as a parameter as either `threadMethod1` or `threadMethod2` are supposed to be instance-methods, and the code inside them will see the same reference of the `TLS` variable.

I want to point out that you aren't using default coding standarts for the C# - the class names and method names aren't in [CamelCasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase), for example. I think that your code needs to be formatted properly.

Also I want to note that the `threadMethod1` or `threadMethod2` shouldn't be `public` as they are called from inside the class only, and you should restrict other classes from using them (if I understood your architecture well).

[Good reference about `TLS` (thread-local-storage) from comments.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I se several things to take instó account developing a multithreading solution

A master thread si nedeed just in case in the future a threads handler is nedeed, flor example to monitor the thread state. Below a basic master thread.

```
public MasterThread
{
    private ConcurrentBag<MyThreadImplementation> threadList;

    public MasterThread()
    {
        threadList = new ConcurrentBag<MyThreadImplementation>();
    }

    public void LaunchThread(MyThreadImplementation newThread)
    {
        threadList.Add(newThread);
        newThread.Start();
    }
}
```

Note MyThreadImplementation would be an interfase or abstract class that defines the shared methods of all the threads you want to implement, or the Thread class if you don't need comcrete implementation or logic in your threads. I would suggest the abstract class below

```
public abstract class MyThreadImplememtation : Thread
{
    private List<YourObject> privateList;

    public MyThreadImplementation()
    {
        list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
    }

    // it will be executed when Thread.start() is called 
    public void run()
    {
        CommonMethod();
        ConcreteMethod();
    }

    public void CommonMethod()
    {
        // common method to all threads, it can manipulate the private list 
    }

    // abstract method to be implemented by the children clases
    public abstract void ConcreteMethod();
}
```

Note that all your threads will inheritance from MyThreadImplementation and implementing its own logic, each one will have its own private list and its own logic, except the CommonMethod that will be the same for all the threads. Also, the main logic of the threads will run first CommonMethod and after that ConcreteMethod.

An example of a thread:

```
public class WhateverThread : MyThreadImplementation
{
    public override void ConcreteMethod()
    {
        // manipulate the private list
        list.Add(new YourObject());
    }
}
```

Comment: `List<T>` class is NOT a thread safe! So you code could create a bugs in multi-threaded enviropnment

Comment: Yes, you're right, I've edited to ConcurrentBag. Thanks.